# How can i create a macro in Microsoft Excel 2010 for uploading html files extract html tables and insert in excel sheet?

Tags: html, excel, evernote, vba

I have many html files in a local folder generated by evernote.
I would like to create a macro that permit to uploading or 1 file step by step or the whole folder and insert the html table data in one row of the excel sheet.

html file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>42</title>
  <basefont face="Tahoma" size="2" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="exporter-version" content="Evernote Windows/271108 (it-IT); Windows/6.3.9600;"/>
  <style>
    body, td {
      font-family: Tahoma;
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<a name="1204"/>
<h1>42</h1>
<div>
<table bgcolor="#D4DDE5" border="0">
<tr><td><b>Creato:</b></td><td><i>29/04/2014 14.41</i></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Aggiornato:</b></td><td><i>29/04/2014 15.48</i></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Posizione:</b></td><td><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?z=6&q=45.803800,10.069100"><i>45°48'14 N  10°4'9 E</i></a></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Tag:</b></td><td><i>tag field</i></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br/>

<div><div style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;"><div> note field </div><div><img src="42_files/Immagine.jpeg" type="image/jpeg"/></div><div></div></div>
</div></body></html>
```

In the excel file there is a table with ID field, date field, tag field, image link field and note field.

I have to convert every html file in an excel row.

I found this partial hint [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zJ3_hrkW40UjMyb0JnX0JxMkU/edit?usp=sharing) and [here](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010400_Importing_Multiple_Files_to_a_Single_Workbook.html) but i'm new in macro programming.

**UPDATE**

I record a macro, and i got this opening only one html file:

```
***************************************************
'This function will write the web page source to file
'****************************************************

Public Function fncWriteSource(sUrl As String, sFile As String) As Boolean


    FileNum = FreeFile

    'write the web page source to the temp file
    Open sFile For Output As FileNum
    Print #FileNum, fncGetSource(sUrl)
    Close FileNum

    fncWriteSource = True


    Application.Goto Reference:="fluido2"

    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Windows("FT-Survey.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 14
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 17
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 18
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 17
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 14
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 14
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    Windows("provafluidomacro.xlsm").Activate
End Function
```

Now i think i need something for converting all this stuff in only one row with the previous field listed and a little mask for uploading the whole folder or one file.

**UPDATE #2**

I attached my zip wth html file for exporting in the excel file!
[zip with html files and images](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zJ3_hrkW40UjMyb0JnX0JxMkU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try recording a macro while opening one of those HTML files in Excel. Then build on that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Prerequisites: Excel file running the VBA code is in the same directory as the HTML files. The HTML files have consecutive numeric names e.g.: 1.html, 2.html and etc. Worksheet named Sheet1 has ID in column B, Date in column C, Tag in column D, Image Link in column E, Note in column F.

Scenario: the VBA code opens the HTML files one after another and copies the required data into a blank row of a worksheet.

Step 1: Open the excel file, click F11, then Tools / References... Find Microsoft Internet Controls in the list, put check it and click OK.

The code:

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

ie.Silent = True
ie.Visible = False

Dim a As Integer
a = 1
For a = 1 To 100 'here goes last HTML file name instead of 100
    ie.Navigate ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & a & ".html"
    While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Dim b As Integer, d As Integer
    Dim c As Long
    Dim id As String, dat As String, link As String, tags As String, note As String

    id = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("Title")(0).innertext

    d = 0
    While ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(d) Is Nothing = False
        d = d + 1
    Wend
    d = d - 1

    For b = 0 To d
        MsgBox ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(b).innertext & b
        If ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(b).innertext = "Creato:" Then
            dat = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(b + 1).innertext
        End If
        If ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(b).innertext = "Tag:" Then
            tags = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(b + 1).innertext
        End If
        If ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(b) Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next b

    link = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")(1).href

    d = 0
    While ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")(d) Is Nothing = False
        d = d + 1
    Wend
    d = d - 3

    note = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")(d).innertext

    For c = 2 To 1048576
        If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("A" & c)) Then
            Sheet1.Range("A" & c) = a
            Sheet1.Range("B" & c) = id
            Sheet1.Range("C" & c) = dat
            Sheet1.Range("E" & c) = link
            Sheet1.Range("D" & c) = tags
            Sheet1.Range("F" & c) = note
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
Next a

ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: It responds that SHDocVw.InternetExplorer is undefined and if it is related with:  "Tools / References... Find Microsoft Internet Controls in the list, put check it and click OK.", in tools i have got "macro", "options", "VBA projects proprieties" and "digital sign" but no "references"

Comment: What is you Excel version? "References" should be the very first entry in the "Tools" menu.

Comment: "References" is the very first entry in VBE Tools menu in Excel 2013. Microsoft Internet Controls reference is necessary to run the code.

Comment: It is the first: "riferimenti" (references) but i cannot click on it!

Comment: I am sorry but I really don't have answer for that.

Comment: ok i solve it, because when macro is running "references" is not cliccable, now i rerun the macro but i got a run time error: '2147467259 (80004005)': automation error. Then, the debug show the error here: If Left(ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")(b).innertext, 7) = "Creato:" Then

Comment: error: Method 'Navigate' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed at this line: While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE after it opens the first html file

Comment: But i do not want open the html file, only copyng the data stored in the html file to the excel file!

Comment: I performed several tests based on you html code with MS Excel 2013 and MS Internet Explorer 11. All tests were successful. In order to copy data from the html file to the excel file, it is necessary to open the html file. Check path, permission and your web browser. Study the suggested code and make relevant adjustments.

Comment: but i do not figure out why open the first file and does not write anything in the excel file, and why stop only after the first file! THis line While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE i think it means that if ie is busy that it has to wait! From this line: For c = 2 To 1048576you write data in excel.

Comment: if  i delete the while cycle the run time error is shifted here: id = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("Title")(0).innertext

Comment: Don't remove any piece of code except the line with msgbox! I forgot to delete it.

Comment: I remove pieces of code because i can see what happens, i try figure out what goes wrong!

Comment: At the end of my question a linked the zip file with a bunch of html files,now u can see there is a run time error after the first file execution !

Comment: Hello. The code runs without errors. As indicated in my comment above, you should remove the MsgBox line as it displays a message box, which stops the code execution until OK button is clicked in the message box (which is displayed on excel sheet, not the VBA Editor). If random parts of the code are removed, you will receive random error codes. Good luck with experimenting. Bye.

Comment: link fixed! Now i check the random error code! thanks!

Comment: the error here: While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE is that the server not exist oris not avaible and the readystate_complete = 4.

Comment: My friend there is no error in the code, just remove the msgbox line. the file names you provided are not continuous: e.g.: after 62 there is 125 and they don't start form 1.html either. You need file names to be continuous and start from 1.html.

Comment: I just tested your files and the code works fine until it reaches file 63, which is not there, so it gives an error.

Comment: well, the debug continue show me error here: While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE. open only 42.html and it opens a window: run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' automation error